# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, nonetype

I'm getting this error:

```
[...], line 28, in <module>
    PlayerDamage = Dice * int(set_p_w.player_damage)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'player_damage'
```

When I run this code:

```
import player
Dice = random.randrange(1, 7)
set_p_w = player.set_player_weapon()
PlayerDamage = Dice * set_p_w.player_damage
```

This is how `player.set_player_weapon()` looks like:

```
def set_player_weapon():
    import items
    player_weapon = items.WBrokenSword
    player_damage = player_weapon.damage
```

I searched everywhere and tried a bunch of different solutions, but nothing helped me. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What value does `set_player_weapon()` return?

Comment: Do you have any documentation on how the `player` module works?

Comment: `return set_player_weapon()
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: What do you mean, @FabianYing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, `player.set_player_weapon()` doesn’t return anything. So `set_p_w` is nothing. You are interacting with `set_p_w` as if it is an object, but `set_player_weapon()` doesn’t create an object, it just sets two local variables (`player_weapon` and `player_damage`) and then discards them when the function ends.

The simplest way to get this to work is to have your `player.set_player_weapon()` method return a tuple with that information so it can be stored in the a variable outside the function: `(player_weapon, player_damage)`.

**Tuple Method**

```
def set_player_weapon():
    import items
    player_weapon = items.WBrokenSword
    player_damage = player_weapon.damage
    return (player_weapon, player_damage)

player_weapon_damage = player.set_player_weapon()
PlayerDamage = Dice * player_weapon_damage[0]
```

A better way would be to make an class for `Player` which has the attributes `player_weapon` and `player_damage` as well as methods like `def set_player_weapon()` that set and change its attributes.

Comment: I did this : `def set_player_weapon():
        import items
        player_weapon = items.WBrokenSword
        player_damage = player_weapon.damage
        return player_weapon, player_damage`, that resulted in this: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'player_damage'`

Comment: Only objects have attributes that can be accessed with dot notation. You access data in tuples either by unpacking them into variables: `weapon, damage = set_p_w` or with bracket notation: `player_damage = set_p_w[0]`